# How to integrate the LDAP system to my existing java based website

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, ldap, data-synchronization

We also have a requirement where we needs to associate the LDAP users with our application.

Going through the below link gives me some of the idea.
[How to build LDAP integration for my web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761966/how-to-build-ldap-integration-for-my-web-app)

Still some of the questions remains

Application is basically servlet based application with Ext-js as the front end.
This requirement is particularly for one of the clients.

Our application is basically a SAAS application with Role Based Access Control system . We have users with different roles Admin,Staff etc with different set of permissions.

How do we achieve the same in our application , i mean the authorization part,assuming that authentication is already done with some e "remote authentication" feature already implemented.

- Do we really need to import these all LDAP users to our application ? if yes how to do it?
- How to map our existing roles to this users.
- Do we need a Domain Server to test this feature. How can we setup . One of my friend advised to install windows 2008 server to achieve the same. is it really needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we really need to import these all LDAP users to our application?

No, they're in the LDAP DIT, that's where they should stay.

> if yes how to do it?

Don't.

> How to map our existing roles to this users.

Add the *roles* to the LDAP DIT and enrol the users in those roles in the LDAP DIT as appropriate.

> Do we need a Domain Server to test this feature.

You need an LDAP server. There are many available.

> How can we setup.

Off topic. Try superuser.com.

> One of my friend advised to install windows 2008 server to achieve the same. Is it really needed ?

No, there are many LDAP servers available, see above. Active Directory is just one of those.